# What is the correct repository details for qemu on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: ubuntu, virtualization, qemu, repository, virt-manager

I'm attempting to setup qemu-kvm on Ubuntu 18.04. I have installed qemu - fine. I am now trying to install/setup vm images, however the virt-install command is not found.

I have tried to add the qemu repositories so that I might be able to install virt-install:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:qemu/ppa
$ sudo apt-get update
```

However, when update runs I get the following:

```
...
Err:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/qemu/ppa/ubuntu bionic Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/qemu/ppa/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
...
```

The add repository commands came from the Launchpad site (https://launchpad.net/~qemu/+archive/ubuntu/ppa).

Does anyone know of a working repository link for qemu under Ubuntu bionic please.

Comment: Further research into the base of this problem - virt-install command not being recognised when attempting to create a VM image. Under older Ubuntu distros, this would be inthe virtinst package.
I now have the understanding that that command should be available in virt-manager for Ubuntu 18.04. I have virt-manager installed, and still virt-install is not found. What gives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ppa had been removed and disabled. There is no daily qemu ppa any more.